# Добавил видео. Как поставить кнопку play-pause при нажатии на само видео, что-то типа youtube плеера

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добавил видео. Как поставить кнопку play-pause при нажатии на само видео, что-то типа youtube плеера без всяких controls, а именно при нажитии на само окно видео оно проигрывалось или же останавливалось . На чистом javascript

```
<div id="content">
        <video class="videoContent" id="video" autoplay ></video>
        <div class="but-link_1" data-video="resources/1.mov" id="first"></div>
        <div class="but-link_2" data-video="resources/2.mov" id="second"></div>
    </div>
var els__butLink = document.querySelectorAll('.but-link_1'),
    el__player = document.querySelector('#video');

els__butLink.forEach(function(el__butLink) {
    el__butLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var str__video = el__butLink.getAttribute('data-video');

        el__player.src = str__video;
        el__player.play();
    });
});

var els__butLink = document.querySelectorAll('.but-link_2'),
    el__player = document.querySelector('#video');

els__butLink.forEach(function(el__butLink) {
    el__butLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var str__video = el__butLink.getAttribute('data-video');

        el__player.src = str__video;
        el__player.play();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');
video.onclick = () => video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
```

```html
        <video width='400' height='300' autoplay>
          <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
        </video>
```

Comment: работает, но как сделать чтобы появлялась иконочка play-pause ?

Comment: ну найти иконку в интернете и сдесь же в функции добавилять ее или убирать. Это по разному можно.

Comment: что написать нужно ?для добавления можно по подробней